# How to write generic catamorphism type and function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to design a catamorphism type for use with unions in typescript -

```
type Kind<K extends string, V> = { kind: K, value: V }

type UseAsyncHookState<T> =
  | Kind<"loading", null>
  | Kind<"error", Error>
  | Kind<"result", T>

type Cata<T,Result> = {                       // type Cata<T, Result> = {
    [K in UseAsyncHookState<T> as K["kind"]]: //   loading: (value: null) => Result;
      (value: K["value"]) => Result           //   error: (value: Error) => Result;
}                                             //   result: (value: T) => Result;
                                              // } ✅

function cata<T,Result>(t: T, map: Cata<T,Result>): Result {
  return map[t.kind](t.value) // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
                              // expression of type 'any' can't be used to
                              // index type 'Cata<T, Result>' ❌
}
```

I can construct a static `Cata` type that adds a property for each kind in my union, but I'm running into two issues -

1. I would like `Cata` to be generic so I can construct a type on-the-fly for any union of kinds. The example above is locked to `UseAsyncStateHook`
2. The `cata` function is improperly typed and I'm unsure how to fix it

Here's another attempt with a simplified `Shape` example, hopefully clarifying how `Cata` and `cata` would be useful -

```
type Kind<K extends string, V> = { kind: K, value: V }

type Cata<T, Result> = {
  [K in T["kind"]]:  // ❌ Type 'T["kind"]' is not assignable to 
                     // type 'string | number | symbol'
                     // Type '"kind"' cannot be used to index type 'T'
    (value: T["value"]) => Result
      // ❌ Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'T'
  
}

type Shape =
  | Kind<"circle", { radius: number }>
  | Kind<"rectangle", { width: number, height: number }>
  | Kind<"triangle", { base: number, height: number }>

function cata<T, Result>(t: T, map: Cata<T, Result>): Result {
  return map[t.kind](t.value) // ❌ same
}

const shapeCata: Cata<Shape, number> = {
  circle: ({ radius }) => Math.PI * radius ** 2,
  rectangle: ({ width, height }) => width * height,
  triangle: ({ base, height }) => 0.5 * base * height
}

const circle: Shape = { kind: "circle", value: { radius: 2 } }
const rectangle: Shape = { kind: "rectangle", value: { width: 3, height: 4 } }
const triangle: Shape = { kind: "triangle", value: { base: 5, height: 6 } }

console.log(cata(circle, shapeCata)) // 12.566370614359172
console.log(cata(rectangle, shapeCata)) // 12
console.log(cata(triangle, shapeCata)) // 15
```

**attempt 2**

I am [making progress here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgJQKYEMDGMByEAmqcAvnAGZQQhwBEUG2NAUEzAJ5hEDSwAdvgB4ucVAA8YqfgGc4UmFD4BzADRwAagD44AXkRwA1n3wAuOF1UA3dABsArqlNqSLdpzgBVKagCCUtr0wACQgIfQBlGHQJAQAVLW0mODgAHzMjARprCHR8JRpVXltraw1ElLT+DNQoSih8uABRGuhSpNSeSrpUKSKYeriXDiIwgAt0NwSktorBGkxgKExrVHqkKBzgWylTQpAAI2qSVqn29K7sdF5FZdW4AHdgfBgRndt96tUR1GBFEZhX95QI5laYdWbyYCXa4rVRIPboLwAg5QT7fX7-OC7ZHA1hDOAAYSi6FiInEknwMjBAjkCiuqlsvH0vAgd14GlUyHiiBBcAA2u44Hw4DE4AiPLyaIZ+DQALoy0wACisdgc4poyvssoAlDotMgmMQWAB6I1wTAQAL0CRmolwVzde7QfQAQlxblG4x89HQOgJRIEHs4BTeyNKJrteMDXowvoQTHDUzNCyWqqVNnspjjCcTU3WuS2SOqAG546bE8QddotFji6Wc-QLldloqNaqs2Wc0kHk8XpiQ7Xs52vj8-oWoCXByRK9X++O64mIVDm3A0yrM-PO3B4Yi+4CJx2h2jR7vkfucxXdSeB6bDW6iL5-EEQvp8VRILxJDBYlzCZEBJ4fD8AJglCCIolQb8OQYXACFQMNTXtOAH2A59X3AC1P2-WMNySLINiuFt01VQpimnFBoLwQgz0TapakItdGmaKAyLQLAYKonC4HoHprAxVcM2FFiKNgs9bzIBlsGAC0bUiZCn1CWJlE5BUMQAuSQPCSJojiVQQHGUxf2JNSgPkzTwMglANC1UxkG5RMrVsKBeDgPSwF5GAADopXwGUVI81sdXDGI8QAchI6wQsFGRmXgBEpB+Xh0D2ZY7QgCM3DC1ALGqEKDRYcSAhgKTnMwIkowEZSMSjXT9L9P9qss6yUDs3NUBgRznNc9yvKMXzPICuAgtC8LIuAaKIFiqR4sURLkqIGA0sQzLsqgXLDSAA) but still running into trouble with the `cata` function -

```
import { ReactNode } from "react"

type Kind<K extends string, V> = { kind: K, value: V }

type UseAsyncHookState<T> =
  | Kind<"loading", null>
  | Kind<"error", Error>
  | Kind<"result", T>

type Shape =
  | Kind<"circle", { radius: number }>
  | Kind<"rectangle", { width: number, height: number }>
  | Kind<"triangle", { base: number, height: number }>

type Cata<T extends Kind<string, unknown>, R> = {
  [U in T as U["kind"]]: (value: U["value"]) => R
}
```

```
// concrete cata types work!
type ShapeArea = Cata<Shape, number>
// type ShapeArea = {
//     circle: (value: {
//         radius: number;
//     }) => number;
//     rectangle: (value: {
//         width: number;
//         height: number;
//     }) => number;
//     triangle: (value: {
//         base: number;
//         height: number;
//     }) => number;
// }

type AsyncHookComponent<T> = Cata<UseAsyncHookState<T>, ReactNode>
// type AsyncHookComponent<T> = {
//     loading: (value: null) => ReactNode;
//     error: (value: Error) => ReactNode;
//     result: (value: T) => ReactNode;
// }
```

If I must define a separate `cata*` function for each type, that's okay, but it's still incorrect -

```
function cataAsyncHook<T,R>(t: UseAsyncHookState<T>, map: Cata<UseAsyncHookState<T>, R>): R {
  return map[t.kind](t.value) // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'
}

function cataShape<R>(t: Shape, map: Cata<Shape, R>): R {
  return map[t.kind](t.value) // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'
}
```

Comment: Does [this refactoring](https://tsplay.dev/mL8avm) meet your needs?  Note that `cata` is not written in terms of `Cata`, but that's probably necessary to get the compiler to follow the logic (and in some sense it doesn't matter if you call `cata(t, weirdMap)` where `weirdMap` is not truly a `Cata` for all its keys, as long as it is one for whatever `t.kind` is.  Anyway if that works for you I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks for the reply @jcalz.`cata` needs to be defined in terms of Cata because the the `map` must always include _all_ kind possibilities for the union. it looks like the `Record` you are using could permit a partial object, which is not allowed. I would also like to see `Cata` working with a generic like `UseAsyncHookState<T>`. And if I can be really picky, there would be no use of `any`.

Comment: 1: But *why* is a partial object not allowed?  Note that the apparent type of `circle` is not `Shape` but `Kind<"circle", {radius: number}>` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKPaKw).  The only property of `map` that matters is its `circle` property if you call `cata(circle, ⋯)`.  If you can demonstrate an actual problem, with code, (instead of just saying "that's not allowed"), maybe I can handle it.  But without a code problem it's hard to obey a constraint like "must be defined in terms of `Cata`" when that type isn't going to give you the inference you want.

Comment: 2: What do you mean "working with a generic"?  You can write `type C<T, R> = Cata<UseAsyncHookState<T>, R>`, so if you need something different, I really need to see it demonstrated with code.

Comment: 3: Feel free to use `unknown` instead of `any` if that works for you, but that is out of the scope of the question as asked and I really don't want to digress to talk about it (if I were using `any` in a way that broke an important bit of type safety, that would be different, but this just feels like personal/linter preference and it's probably not a good use of either of our time to worry about it.)

Comment: 1. partial object is not valid because the catamorphism must provide a valid output for eery kind. if the object is partial, such as `cata(someTriangle, { circle: …, rectangle: … })` would fail. i am looking for a strict `cata(valueOfUnion: TypeOfUnion, map: CataOfUnion<TypeOfUnion, Result>): Result` interface.

Comment: 2.`type C<T,R> = Cata<UseAsyncHookState<T>, R>` is precisely what i was asking for. thanks

Comment: 3. I'm somewhat new to TypeScript so forgive my ignorance on the matter, I've never used `unknown` but I'm intolerant to `any` and config doesn't permit it. I don't feel like making an exception for what should be a well-typed function. If I have to statically code the type for `map` that's easy and avoids `any`, I was just hoping to derive it using TypeScript's higher-level features.

Comment: and btw, thanks for your continued help @jcalz. I've read many of your answers on TypeScript and I value your input on this. I was actually hoping my question would catch your attention.

Comment: 1.  `cata(someTriangle, {circle:  ⋯, rectangle:  ⋯}` will *not* be accepted by my suggested approach (assuming `someTriangle` is of type `Kind<"triangle", ⋯>`); if you think it will be, please [edit] to show me. 2.  So is this part of the question or not? If not, let's leave it there so we can progress toward a solution; if so, please [edit] to make that clear. 3. This `any` talk is mostly a digression; if I can remove `any` from my answer like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgvz1W) I will, if not I will include it and say why.

Comment: Currently [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYerxW) is my suggestion using `unknown` instead of `any` and demonstrating that `cata` will not accept a bad input despite not being defined in terms of `Cata`.  At this point I'm hoping you'll either say "yes that looks good" and I'll write up an answer, or you'll [edit] your code to be a [mre] of a use case this isn't working for, so that I can easily see the problem if I use that solution.  If neither of those is possible then we've probably reached an impasse. How should I proceed?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I am here working on it right now. I appreciate your patience. I made an update to my question now. It's late for me here tonight so I might not be able to make meaningful progress until tomorrow.

Comment: The last edit isn't very promising, unfortunately; you're still focusing on defining `cata` in terms of `Cata` even though the compiler will be unable to see the connection the way you want.  And you haven't demonstrated why it matters (your `someTriangle` issue is demonstrably not accepted).  I guess I'll wait to see if you make a further update with something I consider actionable; otherwise I guess we're not going to see eye-to-eye about it and maybe someone else will meet your needs.  Good night!

Comment: One more possible approach before I run screaming; I can write `cata` in terms of something I call `SomeKind` and `SomeCata` each of which is generic in terms of the full mapping object type instead of a union, and it seems to work exactly how I think meets your needs (see [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5A6MN)). If you like that approach I can write up an answer for that version instead (so now my valid paths forward look like "write up solution A, solution B, get concrete demo of failure for both, or disengage")

Comment: @jcalz this is much closer to what I was looking for, and I now understand what you mean about _"the compiler will be unable to see the connection"_.  I added a few more concrete demos in your [latest playground](https://tsplay.dev/wE8zZW). 1) When a missing kind is not specified in the object, the compiler provides a very helpful hint. 2) The return type of `cata*` can be inferred. and 3) return types in the object cannot be mixed. This is all very lovely, thank you. I'm sorry if I caused you too much stress 

Comment: Okay I will write this version up as an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: No rush. This is a quality-of-life improvement to assist with functional-style programs, as an alternative to imperative style `switch..case`. And although TypeScript 5 has exhaustive switch completions, this shows how it can be accomplished DIY. If you elaborate on implementation, I'm interested to know why `SomeKind<T extends object>` is defined in terms of `object` rather than `Kind`, and the little trick you're doing with `_map` inside `cata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to properly type `Cata<T, R>` for specific `T` and `R` types, we should rewrite your version to something like

```
type Cata<T extends Kind<PropertyKey, unknown>, R> = {
    [U in T as U["kind"]]: (value: U["value"]) => R
}
```

which [constrains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to be some `Kind` type (you can't index into the `kind` or `value` property of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` without knowing that it actually has those properties) and uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to maintain the `kind`-`value` relationship expressed by `T`.  The type parameter `U` iterates over each [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) member of `T`, and you look up `kind` and `value` in `U`.  Your version was looking up `kind` and `value` in `T`, which would give you a union for both with no correlation between them.

You can test that it produces the right type for your `Shape` example:

```
type Shape =
    | Kind<"circle", { radius: number }>
    | Kind<"rectangle", { width: number, height: number }>
    | Kind<"triangle", { base: number, height: number }>

type CSN = Cata<Shape, number>;
/* type CSN = {
    circle: (value: { radius: number; }) => number;
    rectangle: (value: { width: number; height: number; }) => number;
    triangle: (value: { base: number; height: number; }) => number;
} */
```

---

Then, in order for the TypeScript compiler to see the single line `map[t.kind](t.value)` as valid inside the `cata()` implementation, it needs to be the case that `map[t.kind]` is seen to be a function type like `(arg: XXX) => YYY` for some `XXX` and `YYY`, and for `t.value` to be of type `XXX` for the same `XXX`, no matter what `t` turns out to be.  But if `t` will be of some [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to such a union), then the compiler is unable to follow the correlation between the type of `t.kind` and the type of `t.value`, both of which would necessarily be union types.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

And the recommended approach to deal with such situations is a particular sort of generic refactoring as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) (see that issue for details).  You need to come up with a base *mapping object type* and then represent all operations in terms of generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into either that type or a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

If I do that with your `cata()` function, it results in this:

```
type SomeKind<T extends object> =
    { [P in keyof T]: { kind: P, value: T[P] } }[keyof T];

type SomeCata<T extends object, R> =
    { [P in keyof T]: (value: T[P]) => R };

function cata<T extends object, R>(
    t: SomeKind<T>,
    map: SomeCata<T, R>
): R {        
    return map[t.kind](t.value); // okay
}
```

In these cases, the generic type `T` acts as the mapping interface we need for the described.  For `Shape`, the mapping object type would look like

```
interface ShapeMap {
    circle: { radius: number }
    rectangle: { width: number, height: number }
    triangle: { base: number, height: number }
}
```

And you can verify that `SomeKind<ShapeMap>` is equivalent to `Shape` and that `SomeCata<ShapeMap, R>` is equivalent to `Cata<Shape, R>` for all `R`:

```
type SomeShapeKind = SomeKind<ShapeMap>
declare var s: Shape;
declare var s: SomeShapeKind; // okay, these are seen as the same type

type SomeShapeCata = SomeCata<ShapeMap, number>;
declare var c: CSN;
declare var c: SomeShapeCata; // okay, thes are seen as the same type
```

Inside the body of `cata` you can see that `t.kind` is of type `keyof T`, and `t.value` is of type `T[keyof T]`, and that `map[t.kind]` is of a type equivalent to `(value: T[keyof T]) => R`, which works.  Technically the refactoring described at ms/TS#47109 requires that it also be generic in `K extends keyof T`, and then you'd have `t.kind` be of type `K`, `t.value` be of type `T[K]`, and `map[t.kind]` be of type `(value: T[K]) => R`, but it's not necessary to get the code to compiler and isn't of much use to the caller's side, since `T` is already generic.  So I leave it out.

And that would be the end of it, except that TypeScript doesn't properly infer `R` from calls to `cata()` with this version ☹:

```
const shapeCata: Cata<Shape, number> = {
    circle: ({ radius }) => Math.PI * radius ** 2,
    rectangle: ({ width, height }) => width * height,
    triangle: ({ base, height }) => 0.5 * base * height
}

const circle: Shape = { kind: "circle", value: { radius: 2 } };

const hmm = cata(circle, shapeCata);
// cata<ShapeMap, unknown>(
//   t: SomeKind<ShapeMap>, map: SomeCata<ShapeMap, unknown>
// ): unknown
// const hmm: unknown
```

Oops, `R` was inferred as `unknown`.  That's not *wrong* but it's less specific than we want.  We could always manually specify the types:

```
const okay = cata<ShapeMap, number>(circle, shapeCata); 
// const okay: number
```

but part of the point of TypeScript is to have useful type inference.

---

The minimum refactoring I could do here that seems to work is to tell the compiler that `map` must be both a `SomeCata<T, R>` and a `Cata<SomeKind<T>, R>`.  Those are essentially always the same type, but the compiler cannot see their equivalence in the abstract.  And `SomeCata<T, R>` is good for type manipulation inside `cata()`, while `Cata<SomeKind<T>, R>` is better for inference of the `R` type argument.

Which brings us to this:

```
function cata<T extends object, R>(
    t: SomeKind<T>,
    map: SomeCata<T, R> & Cata<SomeKind<T>, R>
): R {
    const _map: SomeCata<T, R> = map;
    return _map[t.kind](t.value);
}
```

The [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) means that `map` must be both of those types.  Inside the function body I can't leave it that way or the compiler gets confused again by `map[t.kind](t.value)`.  We want `map` inside the function only to be seen as `SomeCata<T, R>`.  One easy way to do that is to manually widen `map` to that type by assigning it to a new variable.  So that's what I've done.

And now when you call it inference works as desired:

```
const okay = cata(circle, shapeCata);
// cata<ShapeMap, number>(
//   t: SomeKind<ShapeMap>, map: SomeCata<ShapeMap, number>
// ): number
// const okay: number
```

---

Great, that's it.  Let's make sure it works for the use cases we care about.

Here we see that the compiler is happy when it doesn't know the exact `kind` of the shape (with `circle` the compiler can use [narrowing on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to know that it's a `Kind<'circle',⋯>` and not just a `Shape`:

```
function foo(x: Shape) {
    const num = cata(x, shapeCata); 
    num - 3; // okay
}
```

Here we see that when assignment narrowing does take place, you are allowed to call `cata` with a "partial" `map`, as long as it contains an entry corresponding to the known `kind` of the shape:

```
type NonTriangle =
    Exclude<Shape, Kind<"triangle", unknown>>;
const nonTriangleCata: Cata<NonTriangle, number> = {
    circle: ({ radius }) => Math.PI * radius * 2,
    rectangle: ({ width, height }) => width * 2 + height * 2
}

cata(circle, nonTriangleCata); // okay
cata(rectangle, nonTriangleCata); // okay
cata(triangle, nonTriangleCata); // error
```

Here we see that we can narrow `cata` to only work on specified kinds of things if we really want:

```
const cataAsyncHook: <T, R>(
    t: UseAsyncHookState<T>, map: Cata<UseAsyncHookState<T>, R>
) => R = cata;

const cataShape: <R>(
    t: Shape, map: Cata<Shape, R>
) => R = cata;
```

Et cetera.  Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-KA4mYtDCKgckIK3HdBHPKiD0EAA2ei5kCRAcGIcZmmWDCizAWM4yA9dINrGCoHDSMrAUFs8L4oTSM6QQDKjYhxO6KyIxs4y4wWZczNea8cmsqw7LFfTHKMhDAiC+MkNnGoal-TltHSLTdy9DDVUdRkAHoUvfLkg1UhV6AcJxXHcO0lTWPgst9NSPCgU1ir9JFv0gNTcscZw3CYTV7GagrUvSxjPU6CLBDylqEAYsLSG4UQQCizL6ogRr-MM4gmFixNgPob1fSSiEoDS3YJpAbr3zG-aHMW5RKhUPo4WVKUeVRAh+UxHE8WuW57mJMEXk494iCIil-ng4FQWeKFYQlQM7qMB6MUFKBvDYRkrgJO4iRJcEyW+f6qXHbV5AZZkEFZdkMqRSG+RhrE4eWxk-IlW6ZXmarroRTLdGxKAADINBmm7St0SrvEUdrtT8RDX09AB9JnwdZ9n2FNJ1An1Q1jSgKWFXNK0+Fte1MeSyowfY1hGQAH1gUrANWlNQNeGtoNOpz5CYU3zbMOJTIIm3u17MiFps3yHcC535jNqUeLcz36C4TzA9s2d93sv2g+UWF1CWAA5X9A1msMAqWqEUqrVOM44hirdTQTbagnNY+2o9aST4hFb1NtWI3SvvanWv4+oxu6-Hbym5piO1wrzGhJjvue4kqf65YQeoXkSsUuUeSrCUmZZrUjT43LoS7ZrxvnKV1vR-Mn3LMbgOj5C1yWLPjyRKv6fE8H4ylDB5VZvWX86dKreFTOyQMccQoh9QCTAV6NivooTAOTGA6AYhiBQOZhAb+fBtq7XGpNeg-Z6jQAQV6CAuAoDRAWEOL0tRoCLBTldCUs1VS-2VNnbKYBc6LSYLAkBhCkHvgDBnLh8DwG8KaDVBhXJMHpWwXYPBBBCE3hIWQvBlC6gLD6MoRQvUEqbX9NzOqGF2E2RjKLZ8e8Nw6WgmOY8RZ+ylnLFWA+BAKyNmbPMD2D9NwWV8lYhuFkZz3m6K4wIvE26bk8t4uep4LxXh3P4hOwAKjKC0XFaBagsJcUtp+fiHdqzVz0nBJeSgtHuPQj+dJP13an2tn9c+XcoCURfn5OihTNFhRCQ-WaHFsICG4u06pEDwKPxvKJa+0kWmtPFntSa00YpxXWolLkjodpSP2ooXa0UdAALYY3amu0YQ1SlFsyq0tmEzVYYY6Maz0rtUHlco6kzpGxw0YxUgKYLTiFIO0WKXIVpZPmTo7QRQSi7QAIwNgvJJSS5EADsJ5JIgpouRc8ABOEF0KGwTLwK8iA7zPnfJiiU+KG1IBJWBelMFmLsW4q+Rsu0I8Uz-JJYsslUAQXnmUATImdxxikFIOkTAqSIAlBMaFSZBkZmiH5Yy2qohkrzHFQAWnqZIqZB0DZXXTuyXQ9LMKMgAKKYGTJIYBZVQyu1QOHe+-ShoFSYJwzFnpnAIG1VamVAZMqaudTqi5S1S6ujMZuRxPjCzFjsTOINLjGSEq7BOC+ETxx+MbFAAA1I0mcGLKi0rmfpLVOqtrLNVZon5hKwy5tdfmrBqzaV9Pik6l1fEK3pSsGQYgtC1AhBvAAQTwCAQmAAJXl3AljaBwNKBGIdzUoDiB8qCwwbbhnEOIYOgRQ4W2baQYgNs9XEBbcugIq63b6jwJIcQwAbb8ySWFDZ3be1NAHeNQQeghQ00EB2iAN7+2DuHVoCA0p6BM0DG+j9d6v0jt-fzdUOMJVQmSVyWaj7vDClFIK-9Cp3X6N9JB482p2AbIZLCEY8p2iYVeHgJMggPTLmGMZLRcAiM5EI6IYjXSyOiO4jy0gFowBzpo2FTooGf2vq7T2z941v2jsY8R4x3TcL1BPWemp4R6PGQdUyDd7RSDAG3S2zQN4JXAfvdwdI-GxNgajoyGdWZhgZHHNO0gs72g212oAUHIiBkAoKAKAAByddxAvPhAIDUOAeA8CIHaFGuTp7BB0aY5hFgMXiMWlYxUIol7Jk1BAL0SAIw8BjEmDuiASB9MiZA+NYzAmcBRwCC5qqmW+g5by82wrtx8v6iK2QyjYWLP2as+0Gzx47MOdAoyXzgg4sYAtHUELsWgkt2PVFpTsXjwJZxclvMaW3xBcwIVzwBojTOr6HgTVwBO2LtcM13DXIDODvK6Zn95n5iWbC-1hug3evDfmKNjAx4cVTbwDNiL82-IrePGC8iBbXNZegF5we-ngs5s9NEUL7Rqh7BTAsUgai1Bec68MLzKWgA)

Comment: thanks jcalz. the detailed explanation goes a long way here, and helps me understand other areas of TypeScript that were fuzzy to me.